# Python speed up the code for reconstructing lists

Tags: python, performance, list

What I have been trying to do is reconstructing some lists such as:

```
[42351, 4253, 1264, 5311, 3651]  # The first number in a list is an ID
[42352, 4254, 1244, 1246, 5311, 1264, 3651]
[42353, 1254, 1264]
```

into the format like this:

```
# ID \t 1 \t the_second_number_in_a_list \t ID \t 2 \t the_third_number_in_a_list \t ID \t 3 \t the_forth_number_in_a_list ...
42352   1   4254    42352   2   1244    42352   3   1246    42352   4   5311    42352   5   1264    42352   6   3651
42353   1   1254    42353   2   1264
42351   1   4253    42351   2   1264    42351   3   5311    42351   4   3651
```

**My idea was creating an intermediate dictionary with the desired format:**

```
list_dic = {42352: [42352, 1, 4254, 42352, 2, 1244, 42352, 3, 1246, 42352, 4, 5311, 42352, 5, 1264, 42352, 6, 3651], 42353: [42353, 1, 1254, 42353, 2, 1264], 42351: [42351, 1, 4253, 42351, 2, 1264, 42351, 3, 5311, 42351, 4, 3651]}
```

And then save it to a txt file separated by tab.

However, I realized that in reality I may have hundreds of thousands of lists, and my way would be slow and computationally expensive. **I'm looking for advices to speed up my code and reduce the memory needed for the whole procedure.** Thanks.

---

Attached is my code:

```
seq1 = [42351, 4253, 1264, 5311, 3651]
seq2 = [42352, 4254, 1244, 1246, 5311, 1264, 3651]
seq3 = [42353, 1254, 1264]

# First, group all information into a single list
seq_list = [seq1, seq2, seq3]

# Second, construct a dictionary to store all information
list_dic = {} 
for each_seq in seq_list:
    j = 1
    list_dic[each_seq[0]] = []
    for each_item in each_seq[1:]:
        list_dic[each_seq[0]].append(each_seq[0])
        list_dic[each_seq[0]].append(j)
        list_dic[each_seq[0]].append(each_item)
        j += 1

# Third, save the information into a txt file   
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for each_id in list_dic:
    line = '\t'.join(str(each_num) for each_num in list_dic[each_id])
    text_file.write(line+'\n')
text_file.close()
```

Comment: what do you mean its slow? have you actually profiled it? dict lookup and list append is a pretty fast operation? although I can see it being somewhat expensive memory wise I doubt you will be using enough RAM to actually cause any problems

Comment: `enumerate` and `join` items as strings with a tab character.

Comment: I assume since there is a for loop inside a for loop, it might be slow. And using a dictionary to store all information needs too much memory. But honestly, I haven't tested it on the real data since I don't have it right now.

Comment: Thanks Malik Brahimi ! I will try `enumerate` !

Comment: This is a textbook case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain,count,cycle
with open("out.txt","wb") as f:
    for eachlist in alllists:
        merged = zip(cycle([eachlist[0],]),count(1),eachlist[1:])
        f.write( "\t".join( map(str,chain.from_iterable(merged)) ) )
        f.write("\n")
```

as far as I can tell there isnt really any reason to create the intermediate dictionary

(that said your existing solution also seems pretty viable(although a little slower likely)

for @SirParselot

```
>>> seq1 = [42351, 4253, 1264, 5311, 3651]
>>> seq2 = [42352, 4254, 1244, 1246, 5311, 1264, 3651]
>>> seq3 = [42353, 1254, 1264]
>>> alllists = [seq1, seq2, seq3]
>>> for eachlist in alllists:
...     merged = zip(cycle([eachlist[0],]),count(1),eachlist[1:])
...     print "\t".join( map(str,chain.from_iterable(merged)) )
...
42351   1       4253    42351   2       1264    42351   3       5311    42351    4       3651
42352   1       4254    42352   2       1244    42352   3       1246    42352    4       5311    42352   5       1264    42352   6       3651
42353   1       1254    42353   2       1264
```

Comment: I don't get the desired output. It puts all the lists onto one line. I'm using `alllists = [seq1, seq2, seq3]`  to combine my lists. Is that wrong?

Comment: I think thats right ... I added my example where i just print it to my answer

Comment: Well that's weird. I get the right output with print/sys.stdout.write but when I write to the file it doesn't add newline characters

Comment: are you sure you have the `f.write("\n")` ? are you looking at it in some janky text editor like notepad.exe that may not render \n as newlines?

Comment: I am looking at it in notepad so maybe that is it. Sure enough, notepad.exe does not handle newline characters. Although I've always used it before and never had problems

Comment: I use newlines just like that in my other programs though. I don't see why this example breaks it.

Comment: no you are misremembering ... notepad.exe __only__ handles windows newlines .... it will never render a newline with just "\n" ... 99.9% of all other text editors handle "\n" just fine ... maybe you remember looking in wordpad.exe or notepad++.exe as both of those handle \n without problem

Comment: I am definitely using notepad. I just updated some of my working code to have `f.write(some stuff) f.write("\n")`  instead of `f.write(some stuff + "\n")` and opened it in notepad and it works just fine.

Comment: just open the file with a real editor ... and hide notepad.exe so you never open it again that will solve many of life's problems ... here is a simple demo `with open("test22.txt","wb") as f: f.write("asd\nyellow\nblue"); os.startfile("test22.txt")`

Comment: Well I guess I'll do that now I know this happens. Very strange

Comment: (note that if you open the file in non-binary mode(ie open with `w` instead of `wb`)  __python will__ smartly write the proper endline character for you (`\r\n`)... )

Comment: oh I did not know that. That was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are never going to have two or more lists with the same ID so here is my code

```
seq1 = [42351, 4253, 1264, 5311, 3651]
seq2 = [42352, 4254, 1244, 1246, 5311, 1264, 3651]
seq3 = [42353, 1254, 1264]

# First, group all information into a single list
seq_list = [seq1, seq2, seq3]

# Second, put lists directly into text with desired format
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for i in seq_list:
    for j in range(1,len(i)): #skip the first element and go to the end of the list
        text_file.write(str(i[0]) + '\t' + str(j) + '\t' + str(i[j]) + '\t')
    text_file.write('\n')
text_file.close()
```

instead of creating an intermediate dictionary it just puts the lists directly into the text file with the format you described

Comment: You were right the IDs in my data are unique, sorry that I forgot to mention it. Your answer is really helpful to me and I really appreciate it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution not using itertools:

```
sqs = [
    [42351, 4253, 1264, 5311, 3651],
    [42352, 4254, 1244, 1246, 5311, 1264, 3651],
    [42353, 1254, 1264]
]

for sq in sqs:
    gen = ((sq[0], i, v) for i, v in enumerate(sq[1:], 1))
    print(' '.join([str(x) for sub in gen for x in sub]))
```